# AC adapter buzz

Tags: laptop, ac-adapter

Yesterday my laptop was connected to an unsecure power source, and today I'm hearing a weird buzz coming from the AC adapter. It seems to fluctuate depending on the CPU usage :)

Is it something bad? Should I replace the adapter?

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suspect the adapter is beginning to fail.  Better to pay for new adapter now, than a new laptop later.

Comment: My adapter is been buzzing for like 3 years. No failure ever since then. Some adapters just do that. But of course, a replace won't hurt.  Try checking Google for similar cases. (My laptop's adapter is famous about this.)